# How do I best construct complex NiFi routing

Tags: json, apache-kafka, routes, apache-nifi

I'm a total noob when it comes to NiFi - so please feel free to highlight any stupidity/ignorance.

I'm reading messages from a Kafka topic using NiFi.

Each message contains JSON that contains a field called Function and then a whole bunch of different fields, based on the Function. For example, if Function ="Login", you can expect a username and password field, but if Function = "Pay", you can expect "From", "To" and "Amount" fields.

I need to process each type of Function differently. So, basically, I want to read the message from Kafka, determine the function and then route the message, based on the function to the appropriate set of rules.

It sounds like this should be simple - but for one small complication. I have about 500 different types of Functions. So, I don't want to add a RouteOnAttribute node for each function.

Is there a better way to do this? If this was "real code", I suppose that I'm looking for the difference between an "if" statements and some sort of "switch/case" statement....

Comment: Unless you can group the functions somehow then i don't see how it isn't 500 different cases. In code it is either 500 if/else or 500 cases in a switch.

Comment: @Bryan Bende Absolutely correct. I'm not trying to simplify the solution (it's a complex problem and I've simplified it as much as I can). I guess what I was really asking was whether there are any components or patterns in NiFi that helps to structure the flow in a way that is maintainable. Having 500 routers and then multiple logic boxes under that is going to turn the flow into a nightmare. I also don't think having multiple flows is an option - since I'm processing 10's of thousands of records per second.... (or at least I'm meant to be processing that many)

Comment: You would first use EvaluateJsonPath to extract the function into a flow file attribute, then RouteOnAttribute which would need 500 conditions added to it, and then connect each of those 500 conditions to whatever follow on processing is required. The only other thing you could do is implement a custom processor that handles the 500 conditions internally.

Comment: Thanks @BryanBende - that makes good sense. Think I missed the bit where a single RouteOnAttribute could have multiple conditions (that's the switch I was looking for). If you change that last comment to an answer - I'll be happy to accept it, since it actually answered my question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You would first use EvaluateJsonPath to extract the function into a flow file attribute, then RouteOnAttribute which would need 500 conditions added to it, and then connect each of those 500 conditions to whatever follow on processing is required. The only other thing you could do is implement a custom processor that handles the 500 conditions internally.